# Position cursor at desired location iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have custom UITextField which holds data (eg:) for username . I'm trying to place cursor at desired location if I enter wrong data and want to modify it. For eg: If I enter my username as "stcak" instead of "stack" , I need to place cursor at "a" in textField and delete "ca" and modify that with "ac" so i get desired text "stack".

Im not able to place my cursor at desired location. I had to delete entire text

Kindly help me how I can achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **UITextPosion** for set cursor in **UItextField**.

Below Sample code for that:

```
let newposition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: index)
textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newposition!, to: newposition!)
```

Here **index** is **Position of cursor** in text Field.